# TV show with high school kids and monsters

Tags: story-identification, tv

This show was around 2009-2010, at most 2012, and it's with real people. There are 4-5 friends in high school, who weren't friends before, but gather to save the world against various monsters appearing.

I remember they made their own guns, and the male lead had his own car. It was like a cabriolet and a purplish/deep-red color.

It ended with a cliffhanger as

> aliens in the shapes of jellyfishes or some sort like that.

It's not very clear to me. They had a specific name like Busters, but I cannot remember for the life of me.

It's not *The Troop*, I already saw that one. There is this girl with short blonde hair and the main guy is blonde as well.
This is the closest picture I could find that resembled the type of car:

[image: A 1968 maroon Chevrolet Impala convertible]

Comment: if someone posts the correct answer, then you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: And live action, not https://m.imdb.com/title/tt1353145/?

Comment: FWIW, a cabriolet is a car with a roof that folds back, often lumped under the term "convertible" for a car whose roof can be removed.

Comment: Maybeline Lee - You may want to [merge your accounts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Answer (score 7):

The Canadian sci-fi teen show [Monster Warriors](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0491735/) (2006-2008).

> **The series follows the adventures of four teenagers** fighting to safeguard Capital City from the vengeful wrath of insane and disgruntled B-Movie director, Klaus Von Steinhauer, who possesses the ability to bring his cinematic monsters to life. Over the course of the series, various story arcs occur that expand the series cast and city locations. Each week sees **the teens customize common household objects into useful weapons to fight against monstrous creations.**

There's a blonde boy and a blonde girl with short hair and they indeed drive around in a cool purple Cadillac, which you can see near the end of the intro below. It's all pretty campy:

Answer (score 0):

Could this be the 2009 Nickelodeon show *[The Troop](https://nickelodeon.fandom.com/wiki/The_Troop)*?

> The show revolves around Jake, an average teen who wants to create his own comic book series and is enlisted by his school counselor Mr. Stockley to join "The Troop" a secret society that protects the world from monsters and creatures. Additional squad members include his fellow students, Hayley, the most popular girl in school and Felix, the school's main nerd. teenagers are chosen for the troop because their minds are more acceptable to the strange things in the world, but they are old enough to understand the responsibilities that are entitled. it is shown that once you grow to old monsters become more frightening for some it is a small fear for others it becomes completely terrifying to even look at a monster's picture. The pilot was shot in 2008 and the show itself has been described as "Men In Black at a suburban high school".

Comment: Hmm... no special car that I've found yet, as per https://www.imcdb.org/m1131750.html

Answer (score 0):

Might this be *[Todd and the Book of Pure Evil](https://imdb.com/title/tt1558128/)*?

> A stoner metalhead named Todd Smith, his crushee Jenny, his best friend Curtis, and the geeky Hannah, search their high school for a mayhem-causing Satanic spell book, while being opposed by Atticus, the evil guidance councillor.

There is a convertible in [one of the episodes](https://youtu.be/xNsXljr0tgI)

Found in the TV Tropes entry for [Wake Up, Go to School, Save the World](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WakeUpGoToSchoolSaveTheWorld)